# Subscription without any parameters

Tags: scala, rx-scala

I need to write some RxScala code that creates an `Observable` from a text field in Scala Swing.
After looking on Github, I wrote this code, which seems to work:

```
def textValues: Observable[String] = Observable.create[String](observer => {
  observer.onNext(field.text)
  Subscription()
})
```

Where `field.text` gives the current state of the text from that field.

I don't understand this line however:

```
  Subscription()
```

What is this `Subscription` useful for? It doesn't take any parameters so I'm assuming that it can't be used to unsubscribe from the observable I created, since it doesn't even reference this observable.

So what is a `Subscription()` good for?

Why doesn't it take any parameters?

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question about the line:

```scala
Subscription()
```

It creates an *empty subscription*, that is, a subscription which does nothing when `unsubscribe` is called on it (instead of deregistering the event listener).

Second, note that you're using the "old fashioned" way of creating Observables:

```scala
@deprecated("Use [[Observable.apply]] instead", "0.26.2")
def create[T](f: Observer[T] => Subscription): Observable[T]
```

The new way is this one:

```scala
def apply[T](f: Subscriber[T] => Unit): Observable[T]
```

It corresponds to RxJava's `Observable.create`.
If you want to register `unsubscribe` actions with this method, you should use `Subscriber.add(Subscription)`.

And third, let me point you to [RxSwing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwing), which defines all kinds of Observables for Swing Events, so that you don't have to re-implement them yourself. It's written in Java, but it's easily compatible with Scala, as you can see, for instance, in [this example](https://github.com/samuelgruetter/rx-playground/blob/master/RxScalaDict/src/main/scala/RxScalaDict.scala).